# Spring Webflux : How to return HTTP 200 response with body when the called service returns HTTP 201 without body with WebClient?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a microservice (Java+Spring Boot) that receives HTTP requests, and then I invoke a REST API call over HTTP to another service. The called service returns HTTP status 201(no response body), but I need to return HTTP 200 with the response body.

I am using WebClient to call the other service and for 201 status I am using `bodyToMono(Void.class)`.
So how do I return HTTP 200 response body for the clients of my microservice? What's the best practice? Also how to write a Component Test for the service which is invoking the external service which returns HTTP 201?

Update: The current code looks like:

```java
webClient.builder())
        .post()
        .uri("/employee")
        .body(Mono.just(employee), Employee.class)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(status -> status.equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND), response -> Mono.just(new NotFoundException("404 occurred", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.name())))
        .bodyToMono(Void.class)
        .block();
```

Thanks

Comment: Share your code, please.

Comment: `
webClient.builder())
        .post()
        .uri("/employee")
        .body(Mono.just(employee), Employee.class)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(status -> status.equals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND), response -> Mono.just(new NotFoundException("404 occurred", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.name())))
        .bodyToMono(Void.class)
        .block();

`

Comment: Please don't use `.block()` in reactive stack unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: @JoãoDias, correct

Comment: Please dont write code in comments, you can see its completly unreadable. Edit your question to include the code.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, apologies, I will update the post

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem. I think solving like this.

```
           WebClient
            .builder()
            .build()
            .post()
            .uri("/employee")
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> {
                return response
                        .mutate()
                        .body("success")
                        .build()
                        .bodyToMono(String.class);
            });
```

Comment: thanks for the code snippet. I am also throwing Exception in case of 404. Also I need to return a custom object not string.

Comment: Please do not include new requirements ”as you go” as it will make it impossible to answer the question. You ask one question and get one answer. By including new requirements tells us you have not done proper research before asking, not thought out your question and that all you want is a ”copy paste solution”

Comment: @Diego Rocha, thanks for the code snippet, however if i want to the body to return is not a string class, but a Custom Class like MyResponse?